# Py3 - Tiempo de Proceso Rasterstats

Tags: python, python-3.x

Despues de varias pruebas, logré enlazar distintas ideas y obtener un codiga para procesar y extrar data desde multiples tif.

Estoy trabajando con un shape que está subdividido en grillas iguales de 100km2. (550 aprox)

Por otro lado, tengo 13500 tif con informacion satelital diaria desde 1981.

El objetivo fue extraer para cada grilla la informacion diaria promedio. Es decir, estoy procesando 550 grillas x 13500 datos. Esto hace que al menos, mi codigo tarde días en finalizar.

Estoy buscando la forma de reducir el tiempo de proceso (soy bastante novato en Python). Asimismo, estoy pensando en migrar a un server para que realice la tarea. Por ulitmo, la salida en csv es un ejemplo, para tamaña base de datos debería pensar en otras alternativas (escucho recomendaciones tambien).

```
import os, glob
import rasterstats, rasterio
from rasterstats import zonal_stats

polys = r'C:\xxx\xxx\Gridnovaurora.shp'  #Location of my grid shape
rasterfolder = r'C:\xxx\xxxx\img\Global' #Location of the tif files

os.chdir(rasterfolder)

results = {}

for lyr in glob.glob("*.tif") :
results[lyr] = zonal_stats(polys, lyr, stats=['mean'], nodata=-999,all_touched=True, geojson_out=False)

with open('Novaurora.csv', 'w') as f:
[f.write('{0},{1}\n'.format(key, value)) for key, value in results.items()]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Introducción

Python funciona en un solo hilo por defecto. Esto implica que tu programa python no está aprovechando toda la potencia computacional de tu ordenador. Si tienes varios cores, python (con un solo hilo) estaría utilizando uno solo.

Aunque existe la posibilidad de hacer programación multihilo, y así aprovechar los cores que tenga tu máquina. Sin embargo, debido a la existencia de un *lock* en el intérprete (conocido como GIL, de **G**lobal **I**nterpreter **L**ock), los hilos se van turnando a la hora de ejecutar instrucciones python, por lo que no puede haber dos hilos a la vez ejecutando algo (dentro del mismo proceso). Aunque explicar en detalle el GIL llevaría demasiado tiempo y requiere conocimientos profundos de arquitectura del intérprete, la conclusión es: la programación multihilo en python (en general) en lugar de mejorar las prestaciones, las empeora.

¿Qué nos queda? Lo que suele hacerse para poder aprovechar múltiples *cores* es ejecutar varios procesos. Cada proceso tendrá un solo hilo, pero podrá ejecutarse en un core separado. Así, si tienes cuatro cores y lanzas cuatro procesos, siempre que éstos no tengan que comunicarse entre sí y puedan ejecutarse de forma independiente, tu programa terminará en 1/4 del tiempo.

Para programación con múltiples procesos la solución más simple es usar el paquete (incluido *de serie*) `multiprocessing`.

### Multiprocessing

Trabajar con varios procesos, aunque tiene la ventaja de que aprovecha bien los *cores*, tiene el inconveniente de que no se pueden compartir variables, ni llamar a funciones y pasarles parámetros. Al menos en principio. No obstante, gracias al módulo `multiprocessing`, se "simula" la posibilidad de llamar a una función para que ésta se ejecute en otro proceso y que cuando termine te devuelva un resultado. El problema es que para simular eso, lo que python hace "por debajo" es transmitir en un formato intermedio (llamado *pickle*) todos los parámetros al otro proceso, y recibir de la misma forma el resultado. Este pickle se comunica generalmente a través de una *tubería* (pipe) del sistema operativo.

Aunque los detalles son complejos y no es necesario conocerlos para poder usar `multiprocessing` (como vamos a ver enseguida), hay que tener en mente que los parámetros y resultados de lo que lancemos en otro proceso se comunica de forma diferente (y más lenta) a si fuera todo en el mismo proceso. La moraleja: evita enviar grandes cantidades de datos como parámetro o retornar grandes volúmenes de información como resultado.

### Tu caso

En tu caso veo que el procesamiento de cada fichero puede hacerse perfectamente de forma independiente en procesos separados, pues para procesar uno de esos ficheros no necesitas los resultados del procesamiento de otros. Sólo para recogerlos todos los resultados juntos al final es necesario.

La función candidata a ejecutarse en procesos separados sería `zonal_stats()` y veo que los parámetros que recibe son de pequeño tamaño (el nombre de un fichero, algunas cadenas, un booleano, todo muy ligero de cara a pasarlo por un *pickle*). Otra cosa sería si le pasaras el contenido del fichero, pero no es el caso.

Lo que retorna no sé muy bien cuánto ocupará, pues no vemos el código de esa función. Pero supongamos que tampoco retorna grandes cantidades de información.

La forma de paralelizar tu código para que se ejecute en varios procesos sería la siguiente:

```py
# El principio es igual
import os, glob
import rasterstats, rasterio
from rasterstats import zonal_stats

polys = r'C:\xxx\xxx\Gridnovaurora.shp'  #Location of my grid shape
rasterfolder = r'C:\xxx\xxxx\img\Global' #Location of the tif files

os.chdir(rasterfolder)

results = {}


# Ahora definimos una función que procese un solo fichero. 
# Será ejecutada en otro proceso
# Devuelve como resultado el nombre de fichero que ha procesado
# junto con el resultado obtenido para él
def procesar_fichero(nombre):
   resultado = zonal_stats(polys, nombre, stats=['mean'],
                      nodata=-999,all_touched=True, geojson_out=False)
   return (nombre, resultado)

import multiprocessing

# Y esto es lo que cambia. El bucle de procesamiento se cambia por
# lo siguiente:
with multiprocessing.Pool(4) as pool:
    for nombre, resultado in pool.map(procesar_fichero, glob.glob("*.tif")):
        results[nombre] = resultado


# A partir de aqui, vuelve a ser normal, tenemos los resultados en
# el diccionario y los volcamos a un fichero
with open('Novaurora.csv', 'w') as f:
    [f.write('{0},{1}\n'.format(key, value)) for key, value in results.items()]
```

La claves son:

- `with multprocessing.Pool(4) as pool` Sirve para crear un "pool" de 4 procesos. Cada uno de esos procesos se ejecutará en una CPU (o core) diferente. Cambia 4 por el número de cores que tengas en tu máquina. De momento los 4 estarán a la espera de que les mandes trabajo.
- `pool.map()` es una función que espera como primer parámetro un nombre de función y como segundo parámetro un iterable. Lo que hará será enviar al pool un "trabajo" que consiste en ejecutar esa función sobre uno de los elementos que le retorne el iterable. Mientras haya procesos libres en el pool, podrá mandar varios trabajos en paralelo. Por tanto en este caso irá enviando los trabajos de 4 en 4. Nota que lo que le hemos pasado como iterable es la lista de ficheros a procesar.

`pool.map()` espera a que los procesos terminen su trabajo y le devuelvan el resultado, y entonces él retorna lo que el proceso le haya enviado. La interfaz de `pool.map()` es la de un iterador. Si lo usamos en un bucle `for` como en el caso anterior, en cada iteración obtendremos una pareja `nombre, valor`. No llegarán necesariamente en el mismo orden en que las fuimos enviando al pool de procesos, pues depende de lo que tarde en completarse cada uno. Tan pronto como un proceso quede libre, `pool.map()` le enviará el siguiente trabajo.

El código anterior se ejecutará 4 veces más rápido que cuando lo tenías en un solo proceso (asumiendo que tu máquina tiene 4 cores, si sólo tiene 2, irá sólo el doble de rápido o algo menos, pues cada core estará ejecutando dos procesos).

## Actualización

El usuario reportó que cuando añadía `multiprocessing` a su código, éste dejaba de funcionar. Tras una conversación en los comentarios, averiguo que el usuario está trabajando en Windows y en un Jupyter Notebook, y que la celda con ese código nunca termina su ejecución, ni aparece ningún mensaje de los `print()` que añadió al programa cuando se inicia una función.

Probando yo mismo a ejecutar otro ejemplo mínimo de `multiprocessing` en un entorno similar (Windows, Python 3.6, Jupyter Notebook) descubro que efectivamente la celda se queda como "bloqueada". Pero también puedo ver que en la consola windows desde la que lancé el Notebook aparecen varios *strack traces*, con excepciones como `AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'procesar_fichero' on <module '__main__' (built-in)>`

Por tanto, lo que está ocurriendo es que los procesos lanzados desde el proceso principal, están muriendo debido a ese error. El proceso principal se queda esperando sus respuestas, pero éstas nunca llegan.

Y este error aparece sólo cuando se está en Windows y en Jupyter a la vez, debido a que en este caso trabajamos con un intérprete interactivo y no con un script "normal".

Debido a cómo funciona la creación de procesos Windows (que es diferente a Unix), una vez creado el proceso-hijo este nace "vacío" y tiene que hacer un import del módulo en que se estaba ejecutando el padre que lo creó, para localizar en ese módulo la función a ejecutar. Este módulo no existe cuando estamos en un intérprete interactivo y de ahí los problemas.

La solución. Es un poco farragosa pero funciona. Tienes que escribir un fichero .py aparte (y tenerlo en la misma carpeta que el `.ipynb`) que contenga la función a ejecutar. Por ejemplo:

```
# Esto está en un fichero llamado por ejemplo
# mimodulo.py
from rasterstats import zonal_stats

polys = r'C:\xxx\xxx\Gridnovaurora.shp'  #Location of my grid shape
def procesar_fichero(nombre):
   resultado = zonal_stats(polys, nombre, stats=['mean'],
                      nodata=-999,all_touched=True, geojson_out=False)
   return (nombre, resultado)
```

Y ahora, en tu celda del Notebook (necesitas reiniciar el kernel) pondrás:

```
import os, glob
import multiprocessing

from mimodulo import procesar_fichero

rasterfolder = r'C:\xxx\xxxx\img\Global' #Location of the tif files
os.chdir(rasterfolder)
results = {}

with multiprocessing.Pool(4) as pool:
    for nombre, resultado in pool.map(procesar_fichero, glob.glob("*.tif")):
        results[nombre] = resultado
```

Y ya debería funcionar. Ten en cuenta no obstante que si pones `print()` en la función para ver el progreso, el resultado de esos `print()` no se verá en la celda de salida del Notebook, sino en la terminal windows en la que se está ejecutando el comando `jupyter notebook`. Pero aunque no veas esa salida, cuando todos los subprocesos hayan terminado, la celda se desbloqueará y tendrás en la variable `result` la recopilación de los resultados.

Comment: Excelente explicacion y muy util por cierto. Gracias. Avanzando con lo sugerido, apareció algo inesperado (estoy usando Jupyter). ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py in <module>()
    150     # no-one else in the world is using it (though I hope not)
    151     from .testing import Tester
--> 152     test = testing.nosetester._numpy_tester().test
    153     bench = testing.nosetester._numpy_tester().bench
    154 

NameError: name 'testing' is not defined.                                                     Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Gracias. Si he corregido este punto como dices, hubo mezcla de paquetes. Ahora con esto ya limpio, volvi a correr el codigo, pero se queda en Busy y el codigo no finaliza. Que puede estar pasando?

Comment: Si había reailzado algo asi, al incio y final, gracia por el consejo de incluirlo en la función. Habiendo agregado esto, donde se está quedando el codigo es en el llamdo de la funcion, pues, "Comenzando a procesar fichero.." no sale en pantalla. Yo creo que puede haber algo con los inputs del zonal_stats.

Comment: Gracias nuevamente. Si, haciendo una prueba omitiendo el multiprocessing, el codigo funciona, obvimanete, volviendo a la limitacion incial. Voy a consultar en el web que rastertstats si existe alguna incompatibilidad de el threading o hay que trabajarlo de otro manera.

Comment: Es verdad, lo estuve viendo. Probando ejemplos muy sencillos de multiprocessing , tipo n*n, ocurre lo mismo. Hay algo en la pc que pudiera estar bloqueando este comando. Que podrá ser?

Comment: es lo que probe, un simple ejemplo con una funcion n*n y algunos argumentos y pasó lo mismo. Incia pero no pasa nada mas.

Comment: Crees que puede haber alguna restriccion de la corporacion, ya que se trate de una pc laboral?

Comment: @mev87 Creo que he resuelto el problema. Mira la actualización de la respuesta. Voy a borrar todo este hilo de comentarios.

Comment: Funcionó. Gracias!!

Comment: Estoy agregando en el modulo el print para ir viendo el fichero que se procesa: print ("tif: ", nombre.format()) , el tema es que al correr el progrma desde el ipynb, no se está viendo el print. El codigo funcion, se logra procesar todo, pero la variable de control no está saliendo, aun cuando ponga un print sencillo. En el viejo codigo, este print se veía.

Comment: @mev87 sí, ese problema ya lo describo en el último párrafo de la respuesta